# GRUB Installation Problems on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, system-installation

I've been following the Arch Linux installation Wiki, and when trying to install grub, I either get

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `udev`
```

Or

```
/boot doesn't look like an EFI partition
```

Thing is, sda1 is an EFI partition.

I'm lost, can anyone give me a hand?

Edit: I'm installing GRUB with

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB
```

Edit 2: fdisk gives

```
Device ID Type
sda1   ef EFI
sda2   83 Linux
sda3   82 Swap
```

None are bootable, and the partition sizes are 30gb, 430gb and 2gb respectively.

Comment: Please post the results of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (add to your question, please).

Comment: The EFI directory should be `/boot/efi` and make sure sda1 is is mounted to that path.